# Correct way to iterate twice over a list?

Tags: python

What is the correct way to perform multiple iteration over a container? From python documentation:

> Iterator -  A container object (such as a list) produces a fresh new
>   iterator each time you pass it to the iter() function or use it in a
>   for loop. Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same
>   exhausted iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, making
>   it appear like an empty container.
>
> The intention of the protocol is that once an iterator’s next() method
>   raises StopIteration, it will continue to do so on subsequent calls.
>   Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.
>   (This constraint was added in Python 2.3; in Python 2.2, various
>   iterators are broken according to this rule.)

If I have this code:

```
slist = [1,2,3,4]
rlist = reversed(slist)
list(rlist)
#[4,3,2,1]
tuple(rlist)
#()
```

What would be the easiest and most correct way to iterate over 'rlist' twice?

Comment: Note that you're not iterating over a list twice -- That's easy.  You're actually iterating over a `<type 'listreverseiterator'>` twice.

Comment: I've trying to figure this as well, but running list( rlist) returns nothing actually 
So can anyone provide me with an example in which we can't iterate through the same list twice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
rlist = list(reversed(slist))
```

Then iterate as often as you want. This trick applies more generally; whenever you need to iterate over an iterator multiple times, turn it into a list. Here's a code snippet that I keep copy-pasting into different projects for exactly this purpose:

```
def tosequence(it):
    """Turn iterable into a sequence, avoiding a copy if possible."""
    if not isinstance(it, collections.Sequence):
        it = list(it)
    return it
```

(`Sequence` is the abstract type of lists, tuples and many custom list-like objects.)

Comment: Why bother with the test? I expected that there is no cost to `it = list(it)` if `it` is already a list. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't stored the list twice, if you can not combine it to iterate once, then I would

```
slist = [1,2,3,4]
for element in reversed(slist):
    print element  # do first iteration stuff
for element in reversed(slist):
    print element  # do second iteration stuff
```

Just think of the reversed() as setting up a reverse iterator on slist.  The reversed is cheap. That being said, if you only ever need it reversed, I would reverse it and just have it stored like that.

Comment: +1 - Calling `reversed(slist)` only creates a new iterator object which is much cheaper than `list(reversed(slist))` which creates a copy of the entire list.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the correct way to perform multiple iteration over a container?

Just do it twice in a row. No problem.

> What would be the easiest and most correct way to iterate over 'rlist' twice?

See, the reason that isn't working for you is that `rlist` *isn't* "a container".

Notice how

```
list(slist) # another copy of the list
tuple(slist) # still works!
```

So, the simple solution is to just ensure you have an actual container of items if you need to iterate multiple times:

```
rlist = list(reversed(slist)) # we store the result of the first iteration
# and then that result can be iterated over multiple times.
```

If you really must not store the items, try [`itertools.tee`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee). But note that you won't really avoid storing the items if you need to complete one full iteration before starting the next. In the general case, storage is really unavoidable under those restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply reverse the original list in-place (`slist.reverse()`), then iterate over it as many times as you wish, and finally reverse it again to obtain the original list once again?

If this doesn't work for you, the best solution for iterating over the list in reversed order is to create a new reverse iterator every time you need to iterate

```
for _ in xrange(as_many_times_as_i_wish_to_iterate_this_list_in_reverse_order):
    for x in reversed(slist):
        do_stuff(x)
```

Comment: // , Why do you use `_` as a variable name, here? Is that some sort of convention?

Comment: I (and I've seen other people do this) assign throw-away values to an underscore variable. This way when I read the code I'll know immediately that this value is not relevant. 
On the other hand, the `gettext` library uses a `_()` function... so I guess in some contexts this is a bad name for a throw-away variable.